# たらしめる? ex: "素晴らしいfontを素晴らしいものたらしめているのは何かについて学んだ。"

Tags: words

> 素晴らしいcalligraphyを素晴らしいものたらしめているのは何かについて学んだ。

`I studied what makes great calligraphy to be great.`

With regard to **たらしめる** I don't understand that sentence structure. The presence of **を** means there must be a transitive verb in play (**たらしめる**?). But, what is **もの** doing there?

Basically, with regard to sentence structure, what part of speech is "もの"? What does it modify or what is it modified by?

Comment: Maybe this will be of some help http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3306/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check a [Japanese dictionary for たらしめる](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B)？ It comes from たり→たら+しめる.

たり is one of the classical copular verbs and is analyzed as a sound change of と+あり; this is the same と you see in things like [呆然]{ぼうぜん}**と**する.

This is then conjugated to its 未然形 (which naturally mimics あり's): たら.

To this a classical helper verb, しむ, that functions as a type of causative like させる (it has other functions too), and survives in set expressions as しめる in the modern language, is added.

＝たらしめる≈であらせる・にする・にさせる・にしてあるようにする

> 〇〇こそ、人を人たらしめるものだ
>  It is precisely 〇〇 that makes man man.

And もの can be used to give a concrete / obvious feeling to a statement.