# What is らしめる or rather (verb) + あしめる?

Tags: conjugations, history, suffixes

I stumbled upon 死に至らしめました today and since 死に至る exists, at first I was trying to understand the conjugation but then I saw that jisho consider it as a whole verb or expression. There seems to be a couple of verbs having this suffix like 懲らしめる or 成らしめる. Some are considered archaic and almost none are really considered common. Assuming I didn't miss anything obvious, is this an old form of conjugation?

Comment: Does this help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36198/9831 Also related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70475/9831

Answer (score 1):

[しめる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%97%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/#jn-101074) is a causative auxiliary verb. It derived from the archaic [しむ](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009029.htm) and has somewhat limited use.

Since it is a causative, 至らしめる can be written as 至らせる. That said, 死に至らしめる is more like a fixed expression and probably more common than 死に至らせる.

Both 懲らしめる and 成らしめる similarly derived from 懲る (= modern 懲りる) + しめる/成る + しめる. They are recognized almost as independent words ([懲らしめる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%87%B2%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/#jn-82583) has an entry in デジタル大辞泉; 成らしめる doesn't).